# How to manipulate vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to manipulate a set of elements in vectors in c++.

```
vector <int> vectorOfValue;

vectorOfValue.push_back(1);
vectorOfValue.push_back(2);
vectorOfValue.push_back(3);
vectorOfValue.push_back(4);
vectorOfValue.push_back(5);
vectorOfValue.push_back(6);
vectorOfValue.push_back(7);
vectorOfValue.push_back(8);
vectorOfValue.push_back(9);
vectorOfValue.push_back(10);
```

I would like to know how the program can print out the vectors of values bigger 3 and smaller than 9.

It is a set of the data to exclude the outliers for example.

Comment: For example by using an if statement or a predicate

Comment: What you would like to do is very simple, Being able to do just that with help from other SO users is not going to help you in the long run. Please pick up [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basics of the language.

Comment: _I would like to know_ should read: my homework is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short approach of mine using `auto` syntax instead of using `iterator` :

```
for(auto &i : vectorOfValue) {
   if (i > 3 && i < 9) {
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: How do calculate the mean for that set of numbers in this case std::cout << i << std::endl;?

Comment: sum the `i` and store it in a variable, then divide it by the size of data

Comment: you shouldn't use std::endl here and you should not take i per reference

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the standard library algorithms and iterators, you could use std::copy_if:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
  std::vector<int> vectorOfValue;
  // code for initialization of vector ..

  std::copy_if(vectorOfValue.begin(), 
               vectorOfValue.end(), 
               std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"), 
               [](const int value) { return value > 3 && value < 9; });
}
```

Comment: Since the OP says *program can print out the vectors*. A simple iteration would have done. `for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end(); ++it)if(*it>3 && *it<9)cout << *it << ' ';` Any specific reasons for `copy_if` ? Genuinely curious!

Comment: @AditiRawat why not a range-for-loop? `for (auto value : vectorOfValue) if (value > 3 && value < 9) cout << value << ' ';`

Comment: Lately I am minimizing my use of for-loops if there is an appropriate std algorithm, generally prefering the "collections-way" of doing things. You might be interested in this article: https://advancedweb.hu/2017/11/21/a_detailed_case_study_against_for/